# QT Gridlayout Item not highlight after clicking?

Tags: c++, qt, qgridlayout

I have a grid layout as(vtkOpenGLWidget) and inside I distribute the layout in four section. So, I want to highlight the view port when i will clicking on the it.
This is my grid layout image view :

[image]

I will use this code for highlighting the view port
code:

```
void QvtkOpenGLWidgetdrag::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QOpenGLWidget::paintEvent(event);

    QPainter painter(this);

    painter.setPen(QPen(QBrush(Qt::blue), 2));

    if (hasFocus())
        painter.drawRect(QRect(1, 1, width() - 2, height() - 2));
}
```

Its work fine, when i will clicked on the viewport. But i am getting issue when i will select any other module inside the Ui-viewer then it wil by default shows unselected. But, I have selected everytime and once i will select to the other viewport then only it unselect and select to the next view port and vice versa.

Any help is considerable for me.
Thank you in advance

Comment: **Do not** call `paintEvent` manually, e.g. by connecting it to the clicked signal.

Comment: Please, take this code *after* `EDIT`, and post another question, as it introduces a completely different issue. Also put a link the my answer and the exception from your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** Your question is not very clear, so I will try to guess the right solution for you.

## Cause

The focus policy of *QOpenGLWidget* is set to `Qt::NoFocus` by default. Furthermore, this widget does not respect the stylesheet.

## Solution

Subclass *QOpenGLWidget*, change the focus policy to `setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);` and reimplement the `paintEvent` like this:

```
void OpenGLWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QOpenGLWidget::paintEvent(event);

    QPainter painter(this);

    painter.setPen(QPen(QBrush(Qt::magenta), 2));

    if (hasFocus())
        painter.drawRect(QRect(1, 1, width() - 2, height() - 2));
}
```

## Example

In order to demonstrate how to implement that in an application I have prepared a working example for you. The code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/scopchanov/SO-HighlightView).

## Result

This will give you a nice purple border at the edge of the clicked view:

[image]

Comment: All the OpenGLWidget available inside the gridLayout. Still, I will be highlight like this way.

Comment: @AmarKumar, what do you mean by _All the OpenGLWidget available inside the gridLayout_?

Comment: it means grid layout by default take the whole size of OpenGLWidget. when I call (1*1) layout. So, border is created inside the layout or outside the layout

Comment: @AmarKumar, I understand now. So, this approach puts the frame inside the widget.

Comment: I am getting this one error when i used this function inside the mainwindow.cpp, Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF645A9D53F in RadSpaEngine.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000C5A3C03FB0).

Comment: @AmarKumar, the proper thing to do to get help with your problem is not to unaccept the answer, blaming the provided code for causing the given exception, as it was tested and works as expected, but to post another question, in which you show **how you use this code in your program**. Then and only then would someone be able to tell you what is the reason for the crash and how to solve it.

Comment: Everything i am using fine, I will declare  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) inside the QOpenGLWidget class. and try to run this code but lastly i am getting Exception. If you check it once then it will be very usefull for me.

Comment: @AmarKumar, I have added the example. Check it out.

Comment: Can i added your given function inside the mainwindow.cpp

Comment: @AmarKumar, if I understand you correctly, you have to add the class, not the function.

Comment: yes bcz i try to add this function inside the QVTKOpenGLWidget.cxx then it will not work.Also I am not able to create another file with the same name.

Comment: @AmarKumar, do not add this function inside the QVTKOpenGLWidget.cxx. Instead subclass QVTKOpenGLWidget and add it there. Of course, instead of `QOpenGLWidget::paintEvent(event);` you have to call `QVTKOpenGLWidget::paintEvent(event);`.

Comment: Inside this one class( class  QOpenGLWidget : public QWidget) i will put the function but still this one not working.

Comment: @AmarKumar, you have to subclass it, not to change the provided classes.

Comment: please give me example related to mainwindow.cpp

Comment: @AmarKumar, what do you mean by _related to mainwindow.cpp_?

Comment: I need to add this code inside my mainwindow.cpp. I try to add ur mention code inside the subclass of openGl Widget.cpp but it will not response properly.

Comment: @AmarKumar, it is not clear: _inside my mainwindow.cpp_ or _inside the subclass of openGl Widget.cpp_?

Comment: I need to write the code inside the mainwindow.cpp file

Comment: @AmarKumar, I am willing to help you. So, in order to be able to do that, I suggest you to post another question, add a link to this one and describe how do you try to use the code I have written and where you have problems. Then it would be much clearer what should be done.